# comparison of 2 cells with same content but different formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 spreadsheets containing 2 lists which i am comparing to each other. The problem now is, that ,though the the contents are the same, some of the cells get evaluated as text and some as numbers. This even happens when all cell formats are set to text. I made an [example sheet](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=88040460475656258067), where i inserted 2 examples.

When one uses the formula evaluation function, it shows:

`5866863="5866863"=FALSE`

`5865527=5865527=TRUE`

How can i do the comparison, preferably inside the formula. I don't have any clue where to start at or what to search for.

**UPDATE:**
I forgot to mention, that the cells can contain letters in a manner like `M0150`. Is there a way to do a text comparison instead of values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numers formatted as text can be evaluated as numbers through `VALUE()`. It can also be applied to numbers without altering values. So if you are not sure if any of the values compared is text instead of numbers, apply `VALUE()`.

Comparing `A1` with `B1` would look like:

```
=VALUE(A1)=VALUE(B1)
```

Resulting in `TRUE` or `FALSE`

**EDIT**

If your goal is to compare the values as being text just include the `TEXT()` with the correct `@` format. Like so:

```
=TEXT(A1,"@")=TEXT(B1,"@")
```

Returning `TRUE` or `FALSE`

[image]

Comment: It worked for numbers. but i forgot to mention, that there can be preceding letters. i updated the question. but thank you for the answer anyway.

Comment: Very nice. what does the `@` mean?

Comment: @OverflowStacker, it's the placeholder used for text and string when applying a custom format.